# FormsAuthentication causa um erro de redireccionamento infinito - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, forms-authentication

Boa tarde,

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em ASP.NET com C# que requer login, funciona e está a ser usado desta maneira:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FARMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string checkuser = "select count(*) from colaboradores where nrColaborador='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                conn.Close();
                if (temp == 1)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string checkPasswordQuery = "select psw from colaboradores where nrColaborador='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
                    SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
                    string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", " ");

                    if (password == TextBox2.Text)
                    {
                        Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;

                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(temp.ToString(), true);
                        Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("Username ou Password errados");
                    }
                }              
            }
```

Até aqui tudo bem, as coisas complicam quando quero usar o `FormsAuthentication` que causa o erro de reencaminhamento infinito e não consegue abrir o site, chegando a atingir o limite.
Já alterei o `maxUrl` e o `maxUrl` e nada.

```
<requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
```

Já modifiquei o `authentication-mode` e a `authorizathion` e tambem nada:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Menu.aspx"/>
    </authentication>

      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
```

Também já limpei as Cookies do Chrome e nada, tentei com outros browser e o problema aparece igual ou pior.
O que estou a fazer errado? Qual a solução para o meu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mudar o MaxUrl é igual resolver problema de desempenho colocando uma
>   CPU mais forte.

Você está utilizando as 2 opções ao mesmo tempo

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`

e

```
Response.Redirect
```

Sendo que ambos fazem um redirect.

**RedirectFromLoginPage**: *Redireciona um usuário autenticado de volta para a URL originalmente solicitado ou a URL padrão.*

No seu caso acima você utilizando os 2... remova um.

A idéia seria algo do tipo

```
if (password == TextBox2.Text)
{
      Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBox1.Text, true);

} else{
     Response.Write("Username ou Password errados");
}
```

Comment: Bom dia, peço desculpa pela demora na resposta. Fiz como indicado mas  esse mesmo erro continua, é possível que me esteja a faltar alguma parte de código?